# Drupal:I am getting one notification too many times in drupal

Tags: drupal-7

I am using Drupal 7.Here i want to print a notification when some form is added/updated.
here i am getting notification but too many times that notification has been coming.

For example:

Your mail has been sent all member.

Your mail has been sent all member.

Your mail has been sent all member.

like this i am getting one notification too many times.

Here i am using code drupal_set_message('Your mail has been sent all member.');

please any one help me out,i will provide any information to you if you need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `drupal_set_message` is being called many times. Place a [log message](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7) before calling    `drupal_set_message` to trace it.

You can define a boolean variable to check if message have been set already.

Comment: thank you for reply...actually my code having drupal_set_message 4 times,now i comment 3 drupal_set_messages,again it shows one notification 2 times.